# Use if statement for each cell of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, lapply

I have two dataframes, *A* and *B*, each with 64 rows and 431 columns. Each dataframe contains values of zeros and ones. I need to create a new dataframe *C* that has values of 1 when the cell of *A* is equal to the cell of *B*, and a value of 0 when a cell of *A* is different to the cell of *B*. How to apply the if statement to each cell of the two dataframes?

```
Example of dataframes
A <- data.frame(replicate(431,sample(0:1,64,rep=TRUE)))
B <- data.frame(replicate(431,sample(0:1,64,rep=TRUE)))

Example rows from A
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1 0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
2 1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
3 1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0
4 0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0
5 1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1

Example rows from B
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1 1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
2 0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1
3 1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
4 1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
5 0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0

Output I would like to obtain, dataframe C
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
2 0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
3 1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
4 0  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1
5 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of R's behind the scenes magic, you don't even need to use an `if` statement. You can just do this:

```
C <- (A == B) * 1
```

The first part `(A == B)` goes through every cell of A and B and compares them directly. The result is a bunch of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. Multiplying everything by `1` forces the `TRUE` values to become `1` and `FALSE` to become `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You assess whether `A` and `B` are the same (cell-wise) and then transform the `TRUE` / `FALSE` values into binary by multiplying it by 1:

```
df <- (A == B) * 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct. If you really want to use an if statement, then you can use this:

```
C <- ifelse(A == B, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic operations on R matrix-like data structures tend to be cell-wise. Logicals mixed with numbers in operations tend to coerced into the number themselves, 0 (FALSE) and 1 (TRUE) so the `(A == B) + 0` would do what you want to cell-wise, however to make sure that the result is a data.frame and not a matrix you need to call `as.data.frame`:

```
C = as.data.frame((A == B) + 0)
```

Comment: `as.data.frame` is not needed. Yeah, it will give us a matrix, but I doubt that OP really have a preference.